# how to delete tr from table with help of css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to hide current row (value of select) of table with CSS only.

I expect to delete all not `high` level rows when option `high` is selected.

```css
table,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  overflow: hidden;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background-color: #299dff;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

option[value="high"]:checked :not(tr[data-level="high"]) {
  display: none;
}

option[value="medium"]:checked :not(td[data-level="medium"]) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls">
  <label for="level">level</label>
  <select name="level" id="level">
    <option value="high">high</option>
    <option value="medium">medium</option>
    <option value="low">low</option>
  </select>
  <label for="daytime">daytime</label>
  <select name="daytime" id="daytime">
    <option value="first">first</option>
    <option value="second">second</option>
  </select>
  <label for="speciality">speciality</label>
  <select name="speciality" id="speciality">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
  </select>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>speciality</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>level</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>daytime</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-level="high" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="1">
      <td>стоматолог</td>
      <td>комірка 1:2</td>
      <td>комірка 1:3</td>
      <td>комірка 1:4</td>
      <td>комірка 1:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-level="medium" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="2">
      <td>комірка 2:1</td>
      <td>комірка 2:2</td>
      <td>комірка 2:3</td>
      <td>комірка 2:4</td>
      <td>комірка 2:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-level="low" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="3">
      <td>комірка 3:1</td>
      <td>комірка 3:2</td>
      <td>комірка 3:3</td>
      <td>комірка 3:4</td>
      <td>комірка 3:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-level="medium" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="4">
      <td>комірка 4:1</td>
      <td>комірка 4:2</td>
      <td>комірка 4:3</td>
      <td>комірка 4:4</td>
      <td>комірка 4:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-level="high" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="4">
      <td>комірка 5:1</td>
      <td>комірка 5:2</td>
      <td>комірка 5:3</td>
      <td>комірка 5:4</td>
      <td>комірка 5:5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-level="low" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="1">
      <td>комірка 6:1</td>
      <td>комірка 6:2</td>
      <td>комірка 6:3</td>
      <td>комірка 6:4</td>
      <td>комірка 6:5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

My code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oaqkh8n2/).

Comment: CSS can neither 'delete' elements (though it can hide elements), nor style an ancestor based on a descendant. For this you'll need JavaScript (to have it work on the client) or a server-side language (to work on the server).

Comment: @DavidThomas you are right, i need to hide it.

Comment: To hide an element CSS you can use `display: none`, but to trigger the selected event here you should use JavaScript

Comment: @AmineKOUIS i know about display, but are you sure, that css can't do that?

Comment: Yeah I'am sure, you should know that **CSS** is used for the design not to interact with elements like JavaScript do

Comment: css can do it, but as David pointed out, the options are children of a `select` tag and have no way to communicate with something not in the same hierarchy. You would have to make them siblings, for example, which won't work with `option`. You could easily do this with radio buttons however, but that's a design choice

Comment: i respectfully disagree @AmineKOUIS css can be used to interact with elements, sure not on the same level, but things like `:hover`, `:target`, `:focus` etc are helpful css tools

Comment: @WladGuz You can't delete anything by using CSS, ***but*** you can certainly hide elements. CSS is limited in what it can do dynamically, but I did manage to answer you question, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54660982/2813224).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [`visibility: collapse`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/visibility/#article-header-id-2)

Set `visibility: collapse` to each `<tr>` and they will shrink.
In the demo:

- a hidden radio button group is at the top of the `.controls`
- `select#level` was replaced by `details#level` because `<label>` does not function inside an `<option>`
- each `<label>` in `#level` is associated to a radio button by the `[for]` attribute and when clicked, the associated hidden radio button is either `:checked` or not.
- when `:checked` it will trigger a new style that affects a specific .class of `<tr>`

> ```
>  #H:checked~table>tbody>tr.H,
>  #M:checked~table>tbody>tr.M,
>  #L:checked~table>tbody>tr.L {
>    visibility: collapse;
>  }
> ```

The ruleset above declares:

> *"If `#H`, `#M`, or `#L` is `:checked`...
>
>     ...then any sibling `<table>` that follows `~`...
>
>     ...that has a `<tbody>`...
>
>     ...and the `<tbody>` has any `tr.H`, `tr.M`, or `tr.L`...
>
>     ...set `visibility: collapse;` on the appropriate `<tr>`"*

---

### Demo

```css
form {
  width: 100%
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

th {
  width: 20%;
}

td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

tr:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  background-color: #299dff;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.controls {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.daytime {
  margin-left: 15vw;
}

.rad {
  display: none
}

#H:checked~.controls>#level>.H,
#M:checked~.controls>#level>.M,
#L:checked+.controls>#level>.L {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

tr {
  visibility: visible;
}

.rad:checked~table>tbody>tr {
  visibility: collapse;
}

#A:checked~table>tbody>tr,
#H:checked~table>tbody>tr.H,
#M:checked~table>tbody>tr.M,
#L:checked~table>tbody>tr.L {
  visibility: visible;
}

details {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  left: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
}

summary {
  font-size: normal;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

details label {
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <input id='A' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
  <input id='H' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
  <input id='M' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
  <input id='L' class='rad' name='rad' type='radio'>
  <fieldset class="controls">
    <details name="level" id="level">
      <summary>Level</summary>
      <label for='A' class='A'>All</label>
      <label for='H' class='H'>High</label>
      <label for='M' class='M'>Mid</label>
      <label for='L' class='L'>Low</label>
    </details>
    <label for="daytime" class='daytime'>daytime</label>
    <select name="daytime" id="daytime">
      <option value="first">first</option>
      <option value="second">second</option>
    </select>
    <label for="speciality">speciality</label>
    <select name="speciality" id="speciality">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>speciality</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>level</th>
        <th>number</th>
        <th>daytime</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class='H' data-level="high" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="1">
        <td>стоматолог</td>
        <td>комірка 1:2</td>
        <td>комірка 1:3</td>
        <td>комірка 1:4</td>
        <td>комірка 1:5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='M' data-level="mid" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="2">
        <td>комірка 2:1</td>
        <td>комірка 2:2</td>
        <td>комірка 2:3</td>
        <td>комірка 2:4</td>
        <td>комірка 2:5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='L' data-level="low" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="3">
        <td>комірка 3:1</td>
        <td>комірка 3:2</td>
        <td>комірка 3:3</td>
        <td>комірка 3:4</td>
        <td>комірка 3:5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='H' data-level="high" data-daytime="second" data-speciality="4">
        <td>комірка 5:1</td>
        <td>комірка 5:2</td>
        <td>комірка 5:3</td>
        <td>комірка 5:4</td>
        <td>комірка 5:5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='M' data-level="mid" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="4">
        <td>комірка 4:1</td>
        <td>комірка 4:2</td>
        <td>комірка 4:3</td>
        <td>комірка 4:4</td>
        <td>комірка 4:5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class='L' data-level="low" data-daytime="first" data-speciality="1">
        <td>комірка 6:1</td>
        <td>комірка 6:2</td>
        <td>комірка 6:3</td>
        <td>комірка 6:4</td>
        <td>комірка 6:5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: when i chose ``high`` i want to see only high rows. your code hide ``high`` rows when ``high`` is chosen.

Comment: @WladGuz Whoops! Easily fixed, check it now.

Comment: all option now hide hide everything.

Comment: Refresh and check again.

Answer (score 0):

- When you take a CSS selector and make it more specific, you can only access the siblings or the children of your previous selection. This means if a selector starts with `option[value="high"]`, then all you can select by adding something to the right of that selector is the `option` elements that come after it within the same `<select>` tag.
- The `"value"` attribute states what is the value of an option, but not what the selected value is. <strike>There is no way to read the selected value of a `select` in CSS.</strike> As mentionned by **soulshined** in the comments, you need to use `:checked` to select the currently selected `option`.

Comment: `option:checked` targets the selected value of a `select`

Comment: @soulshined For real? Wow, I was certain this couldn't be done. Thanks for the correction.